# Multiple Extra Index URL - pip.ini

Tags: python, windows, azure, pip, devops

When trying to store multiple `extra-index-url` in my `pip.ini` file. I find that I need to have the same username and password for both otherwise I am unable to connect.

```
[global]
extra-index-url = 
    https://user:password@pkgs.dev.azure.com/Colleague_Org/Her_Project/_packaging/Her_Team/pypi/simple/
    https://user2:password2@pkgs.dev.azure.com/My_Org/_packaging/My_Team/pypi/simple/
```

If I create a super token so I can access both artifact libraries with the same token it works fine.

```
[global]
extra-index-url = 
    https://user:super_password@pkgs.dev.azure.com/Colleague_Org/Her_Project/_packaging/Her_Team/pypi/simple/
    https://user:super_password@pkgs.dev.azure.com/My_Org/_packaging/My_Team/pypi/simple/
```

Similarly, if I only use one `extra-index-url` they both work on there own. But together with different tokens, I get the following prompt.

```
User for pkgs.dev.azure.com:
```

Is this user error?

Comment: Hi, could you tell me how you are supplying the PAT?

Comment: Sorry what’s a PAT?

Comment: A personal access token that acts as a password.  Nevermind, I see now you are supplying it directly in the URL.